# Using conditional probability in a tricky way

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I was going through the problem attached herewith. the fact is I could not understand 2 things.

Firstly, how did the author came up with the idea of choosing the event sets the way he has described? How is this intuitive?

Secondly, I tried to find the $P(A_1)$ directly, and I came up with the following way.

$P(A_1)=(C(4,2)\cdot 2!\cdot(14!/(4!^2\cdot3!^2)))/(16!/(4!^4))=12/15$.

I cannot intuitively follow the procedure given here.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: You seem to be missing the problem

Comment: Yeah,sorry...that was stupid of me.

Comment: Edited....It's ok now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may become more intuitive if you introduce event $A0$ as student $1$ occupying any box.

Students $2,3,4$ have to successively occupy a slot from the still **unoccupied group(s)** of $4$ slots

$A0:\;\square\square\fbox{1} \square \quad\square\square \square\square\quad\square\square\square \square\quad\square\square\square \square\quad Pr = 1 $

$A1:\;\square\square\fbox{1} \square \quad\square\square \square\square\quad\fbox{2}\square\square\square\quad\square\square\square \square\quad Pr = 1\cdot \frac{12}{15} $

$A2:\;\square\square\fbox{1} \square \quad\square\square \square\square\quad\fbox{2}\square\square  \square\quad\square\square\square \fbox{3}\quad Pr = 1\cdot \frac{12}{15}\cdot\frac8{14} $

$A3: \;\square\square\fbox{1}\square\quad\square\fbox{4}\square\square\quad\fbox{2}\square\square\square\quad\square\square\square \fbox{3}\quad Pr = 1\cdot \frac{12}{15}\cdot\frac8{14}\cdot\frac4{13} $

We are simply using the multiplication law for dependent events.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a more straightforward way. First place the graduate students in the groups, one in each. This can be done in $4!$ ways. Then we distribute the 12 undergraduate students 3 each to the group in 
\begin{align*}
\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}
\end{align*}
ways. Since 16 students can be divided into 4 groups of 4 each in 
\begin{align*}
\binom{16}{4}\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}
\end{align*}
the desired probability is 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{4!\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}}{\binom{16}{4}\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}} = \frac{64}{455}
\end{align*}

Comment: I know. But I want to follow the footsteps of the author.

Comment: Yes, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think the author is trying to illustrate an application of the definition of conditional probability:
$$P(A\cap B) = P(A) P(A | B).$$
Apply the above twice to $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$. As for why the initial step is $P(A_3) = P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$, that's just personal choice.

What you're deriving is an example of a [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](http://www.randomservices.org/random/urn/MultiHypergeometric.html).